# Работа с PHP JSON MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

1. Есть таблица

   ```
   id  d_id    name  country   lon     lat
   ```
2. Надо в нее записать json

   ```
   [ {
       "id": 707860,
       "name": "Hurzuf",
       "country": "UA",
       "coord": {
         "lon": 34.283333,
         "lat": 44.549999
       }
     },
     {
       "id": 519188,
       "name": "Novinki",
       "country": "RU",
       "coord": {
         "lon": 37.666668,
         "lat": 55.683334
       }
     },
     {
       "id": 1283378,
       "name": "Gorkhā",
       "country": "NP",
       "coord": {
         "lon": 84.633331,
         "lat": 28
       }
     },
     {
       "id": 1270260,
       "name": "State of Haryāna",
       "country": "IN",
       "coord": {
         "lon": 76,
         "lat": 29
       }
     }]
   ```
3. Мой код

   ```
   <?
       include_once('functions.php');
       $pdo = connect();

       $file = file_get_contents('../json/city.list.json');
       $filem = json_decode($file, true);
       if (! is_array($filem)) die ('Json convert error');         

       foreach($filem as $number => $massiv)
           //var_dump($massiv);            
       {                       
           $sql = "insert into `weathers` (d_id, name, country, lon, lat) values (:id, :name, :country, :lon, :lat)";
           $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
           $sth->bindValue(':id', $massiv['id']);
           $sth->bindValue(':name', $massiv['name']);      
           $sth->bindValue(':country', $massiv['country']);
           ?
           ?
           ?
           ?
           ?
           ?
       }
       $sth->execute();                            
   ?>
   ```
4. ВОПРОС: как записать lon и lat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ВОПРОС: как записать lon и lat.

Записать, как есть:

```
$sth->bindValue(':lon', $massiv['coord']['lon']);      
$sth->bindValue(':lat', $massiv['coord']['lat']);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @ЕленаПедаш можете отметить ответ как правильный :)

Comment: @dmitry-maslennikov вы там мастер бессмысленных правок что ли?